# Ejecutar codigo en segundo plano, temporizador ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, timer

el problema es el siguiente, he registrado unos mensajes cada uno con su respectiva fecha [fecha de mostrarse] pro no se como invocarlo, intenté con este `Timer` pero no funciona, de hecho ni siquiera sé como empezar a ejecutarlo ya que `startup.cs` no lo reconoce, lo intente cargar desde `web.config` y tampoco

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Timers;

namespace atlantic.Hubs
{
    public class ModuloTemporizador : IHttpModule
    {

        static Timer _timerGlobal = null;
        static HttpApplication _App;

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            if (_timerGlobal == null)
            {
                context.Application.Lock();
                context.Application["Contador"] = 0L;
                context.Application.UnLock();

                _App = context;

                _timerGlobal = new Timer(1000);
                _timerGlobal.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ProcesoPeriodico);
                _timerGlobal.Start();

            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _timerGlobal = null;
        }        

        private static void ProcesoPeriodico(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            _App.Application.Lock();
            long contador = (long)_App.Application["Contador"];
            _App.Application["Contador"] = contador + 1;
            _App.Application.UnLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Como podria implementar un timer que en ejecute el codigo por minuto que ya la `DB` tengo registrado los mensajes con fecha y hora

Es decir

```
Mensaje{texto:"Este es un mensaje",estado:1,fecha_mostrar:'2020-02-01 15:25:00'}
```

Cunado llegue `2020-02-01 15:25:00` exacatmente a esa hora se vuelve 0 `estado:0` y la proxima vex que entre el usuario este mensaje se le muestra.

O hay otra forma de hacer esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendaria evalues la libreria `Quartz.Net`

[Scheduled Tasks In ASP.NET With Quartz.Net](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/254/scheduled-tasks-in-asp-net-with-quartz-net)

como veras esta permite configurar un `Job`

```
public class NombreJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        //implementacion
    }
}
```

el cual configuras como sera su ejecucion mediante un trigger

```
IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
scheduler.Start();

IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<NombreJob>().Build();

ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
      (s =>
         s.WithIntervalInHours(24)
        .OnEveryDay()
        .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(0, 0))
      )
    .Build();

scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

que puedes lanzar cuando se inicia la aplicacion en el `Global.asax` con el `JobScheduler.Start();`

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //resto codigo
        JobScheduler.Start();
    }
}
```